# Keypress enter on button click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, click, keypress

I would like the keyPress == 13 function to occur when a button has been clicked. Is this possible in Jquery?

Reason why I'm trying to figure this out is because im using a plugin which redirects a search term to an allocated page when pressing the enter key, but this does not work when I click the submit button. So I was wondering If I could  mimic the enter key when button has been click.

Also I apologise for my terminology as I'm a beginner. 
Thanks.

Comment: See the duplicates for more information. Also note that faking key events in the DOM isn't a good idea, and can be flaky depending on the end result you want to achieve. It's a much better idea to separate the required logic into a function and call that directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
$('#yourInput').trigger(e);
```